# Invalid date format issue in Generic Inquiry in Acumatica mobile

Tags: acumatica

I created a Generic Inquiry and Exposed to the Mobile Application. However, I keep getting "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." whenever I open up Filter in mobile app but it works smoothly in web.

Parameters:
[image]

Conditions
[image]

My Appointments screen in Mobile

[image]

Error in Mobile App when go to Filters:

[image]

I checked parameters and conditions with other existing GIs and looks similar to me.

Answer (score 0):

In your paramter StartDate... try @Today-1  That will get you yesterday's date